# How to render file in Rails 5 API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-routing, single-page-application

I have a single-page application written in React with Ruby on Rails back-end (API mode). Rails is also serving static files. I'm pointing Rails router to `public/index.html`, so my SPA could manage his own routing with `react-router`. This is common practice in order to make direct links and refresh to work.

**routes.rb**

```
match '*all', to: 'application#index', via: [:get]
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  def index
    render file: 'public/index.html'
  end
end
```

The problem is this doesn't work in API mode. It's just an empty response. If I change the parent class to `ActionController::Base` everything works as expected. But I don't want to inherit the bloat of full class, I need slim API version.

I've tried adding modules like `ActionController::Renderers::All` and `AbstractController::Rendering` without success.

Comment: try `render_to_string file: 'public/index'`

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon empty response

Comment: add extension and see, `.html`

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon still empty

Comment: did you try `render html: 'file_name'`?

Comment: also try calling from base, `ActionController::Base.helpers.render file: 'public/index.html'`

Comment: Yes, it literally renders the argument as html page. I even tried `render html: File.open('public/index.hml')` with no luck.

Comment: calling render from base should work I think..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> If I change the parent class to ActionController::Base everything works as expected. But I don't want to inherit the bloat of full class, I need slim API version.

Yes, if you serve index from ApplicationController, changing its base class would affect all other controllers. This is not good. But what if you had a specialized controller to serve this page?

```
class StaticPagesController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    render file: 'public/index.html'
  end
end
```

This way, you have only one "bloated" controller and the others remain slim and fast.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
render text: File.read(Rails.root.join('public', 'index.html')), layout: false
```

Comment: This renders the content of the file as text on webpage. Also tried the same with `html:` option.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the question then, but it seems you have an answer now :)

Comment: `text` is deprecated in Rails 5.

Comment: @pj.martorell I think it is now `plain`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just redirect_to 'file path'.

```
def export
    # When the route coming to get 'some_report/export', to: 'greate_controller#export'
    # The file where you write or preparing, then you can redirect some path like : http://localhost:3000/public/tmpfile/report20210507.xlsx
    # And it will just redirect the file for you
    file_path = "public/tmpfile/report20210507.xlsx"
    redirect_to "#{root_url}#{file_path}"
end
```

For this example

root_url = "http://localhost:3000/"

Answer (score -1):

This should work, and allow you to keep inheriting from ActionController::API--

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render body: Rails.root.join('public/index.html').read }
    end
  end
end
```

The render logic changed for ActionController::API with Rails 5.

Comment: It doesn't work `undefined method `respond_to' for #`