# Using "ApplicationController.new.render_to_string" in a Rails api app (config.api_only = true)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, applicationcontroller

I have a Rails 5 app build as an [api app](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html):

```
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.api_only = true
  end
end
```

In one of my controller actions I need to render some Ruby flavoured html, and then serve it back in the json response.

A standard Rails app do this:

```
# app/controllers/my_controller.rb
def my_action
  html = ApplicationController.new.render_to_string("my_erb_or_haml_file", locals: {foo: "bar"}, layout: false)
  render :json => {html: html}, :status => :ok
end
```

However, for my slimmed api app `ApplicationController.new.render_to_string` seems to just render `" "`. This confuses me, because I would expect it to either serve the content or raise an exception.

Any suggestions what route I should take in order to generate Ruby flavoured html?

Comment: Try this maybe? https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/new-feature-in-rails-5-render-views-outside-of-actions

Comment: @SergioTulentsev seems like regardless which of the suggested lines from that post I use, it renders `" "`, e.g. `Rails.logger.error ApplicationController.render(inline: 'erb content').inspect # => " "`.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911928/how-to-render-file-in-rails-5-api

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you have to explicitly use base class. Your application is an API app, so your controller is probably inheriting from ActionController::API

```
ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string
```

Comment: this seems to work. I also tried the suggestion of @TarunLalwani, to inherit that particular controller from `ActionController::Base`. It also worked. Which solution would be considered most lightweight?

Comment: I guess it depends on your use case, if you want to render the html directly, @Tarun lalwani answer is probably 'light weight'. but if you want to return a json that has rendered html as the body/content, ^ is probably more explicit and light weight given it is just a method call rather than whole inheritance of a class.

Comment: Or just `ActionController::Base.render`