# How can I pass a path to a statically served react app from rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app, rails-api

I'm having the following setup:

A `create-react-app` frontend with `react-router` that is bundled into a static asset.
This static asset is served from my `rails-api` project's `public` folder as static files. The react app uses the `rails-api` as backend.
When I go to `/` route, the react app is served and I can navigate my app.

How can I pass any subpaths like `/admin` to the react-router?
I already have a catch-all route in
`config/routes.rb`

```rb
get '*path', to: "application#fallback_index_html", constraints: lambda { |req|
    req.path.exclude? 'rails/active_storage'
  }
```

And I can get the relevant subpath in the controller:

```rb
  def fallback_index_html
    path = request.parameters['path']
    render file: 'public/index.html'
  end
```

But I don't know how to serve the react app *and* pass the path to it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the problem is that my `ApplicationController` is derived from `ActionController::API` instead of `ActionController::Base`. With the Base controller, it works like a charm.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/43912670/526426